# No module named 'airflow.sensors.python_sensor'

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I am trying to use PythonSensor in my dag but I am unable to import it.

```
from airflow.sensors.python_sensor import PythonSensor
    wait_for_stg_completion = PythonSensor(
        task_id='wait_for_stg_completion',
        python_callable=fetch_stg_qa_status
    )
```

How can I import it? What else can I try?

Comment: Did you install its module?

Comment: What other modules did you import?

Comment: PythonSensor was in contrib not in core so it's not the case as dummy. `from airflow.contrib.sensors. python_sensor import PythonSensor` will work for you but it will tell you it's deprecated.

Comment: maybe you can add this as an answer @EladKalif it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Airflow < 2.0.0:

```
from airflow.contrib.sensors.python_sensor import PythonSensor
```

The `PythonSensor` is unique in that matter. One would expect to find it in `airflow.sensors` like other core sensors but that is not the case.

For Airflow >= 2.0.0:

```
from airflow.sensors.python import PythonSensor
```

You can also import from `contrib` but it will show deprecation warning so best to use the updated path.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect import. Use

`from airflow.sensors.python import PythonSensor`

Comment: didn't work either

Comment: @x89 what is your Airflow version?

Comment: airflow version 1.10.13

Comment: For airflow version 1 use `from airflow.contrib.sensors.python_sensor import PythonSensor `